# Change state in array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused.

How change specific element in array of object? For example, i want change **'isComplete'** in object with id=1

[image: state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything like this? In this case your new state depends on the old state so you have to use the setState's function parameter version.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
   const updatedTasks = prevState.task.map(task => {
      return (task.id === 1 ? Object.assign({}, task, {isComplete: !task.isComplete}) : task)
   })
   return {task: updatedTasks}
})
```